# Android, get resource id by string?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Is there a better way to do this:

```
    int drawable;
    switch(mSignalStrength) {
        case 0:
            drawable = R.drawable.signal_0;
            break;
        case 1:
            drawable = R.drawable.signal_1;
            break;
        case 2:
            drawable = R.drawable.signal_2;
            break;
        case 3:
            drawable = R.drawable.signal_3;
            break;
        case 4:
            drawable = R.drawable.signal_4;
            break;
        case 5:
            drawable = R.drawable.signal_5;
            break;
        default:
            drawable = -1;
    }
```

I'm trying to replace the switch statement with some `int getDrawableIdByString("signal_" + mSignalStrength)` function.

Comment: What is the problem in that

Comment: Use reflection: `getIdentifier()`. You can return the resource id by passing its name.

Comment: @warlock I've got the same code repeated 6 times, for different values of signal strength.  That's ugly.

Comment: @chrisdew, this is just a switch case , this will run on behalf of the value provided in mSignalStrength, In that case of repeating you should post the complete problem, what you are trying to achieve and how

Comment: @warlock Thanks, I've amended the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As someone mentioned in the comments, you can use the

`getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)`

For you case, like this

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("signal_" + mSignalStrength, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 2):

By using reflection, you can return the resource id by passing its name.
This is what I use when I need something like that:

1 - Add this method to your code:

```
protected final static int getResourceID
(final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx)
{
    final int ResourceID =
        ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
            ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (ResourceID == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
        (
            "No resource string found with name " + resName
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return ResourceID;
    }
}
```

2 - Use it like this:

```
int myID =
    getResourceID("your_resource_name", "drawable", getApplicationContext());
```

Note (1): no path (and no extension, in case of images).
Note (2): use "drawable" for drawables, "string" for strings, ...

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it is the most readable and robust way.

It allows you to add / remove items later down the line and doesn't tie you in to a specific naming convention.

It's easier to read because you can just click through to the drawable resource from the code and see for yourself exactly which drawable matches which case -- something that becomes a bit harder when you're generating the id this way.